# Angular service subscribe seems to be not working

Tags: angular

I have created a service in Angular, emmit method is working fine as i can see in console.log and debug, but after this the code is doing nothing more and is not taking other lines already using service.subscribe...is like subscribe is doing nothing.

Sevice Code:

```js
import { Injectable, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ServicioDeFavoritosService {
  @Output() disparadorDeFavoritos: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }
}
```

Emmit code:

```js
import { ServicioDeFavoritosService } from './../servicio-de-favoritos.service';
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-card',
  templateUrl: './card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./card.component.css']
})
export class CardComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() dataEntrante: any;
  public image: string = "";

  constructor(public servicioFavorito: ServicioDeFavoritosService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.image="https://www.jquery-az.com/html/images/banana.jpg";
    console.log('Entrando data: ', this.dataEntrante);
  }

  agregarFavorito(dataEntranteParam: any) {
    this.servicioFavorito.disparadorDeFavoritos.emit({
      data: this.dataEntrante
    });
    console.log('Emitiendo data: ', this.dataEntrante);
  }

}
```

Subscribe code

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ServicioDeFavoritosService } from '../servicio-de-favoritos.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.css']
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {

  public listadeVideos: Array<any> = []

  constructor(public servicioFavorito: ServicioDeFavoritosService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.servicioFavorito.disparadorDeFavoritos.subscribe(data => {
      this.listadeVideos.push(data);
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `@Ouput()` decorator is for emitting an event from a child component to a parent component.

For your case, you need a special `observable` which can be a `Subject`, with this, you will be able to communicate between components.

Your service:

```js
import { Injectable, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ServicioDeFavoritosService {
  private yourSubject$ = new Subject();

  emitAValue(value: any) {
    this.yourSubject$.next(value);
  }

  getValueEmitted(): Observable<any> {
    return this.yourSubject$.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Card component:

```js
 agregarFavorito(dataEntranteParam: any) {
    this.servicioFavorito.emitAValue({ data: this.dataEntrante });
 }
```

Sidebar Component

```js
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.servicioFavorito.getValueEmitted().subscribe(
     (yourValue) => console.log(yourValue)
    )
 }
```